# How do you call a web api service from another web api service?

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

I created a Data Access Layer project in my solution that uses Entity Framework/Web API. Happy with my results after some testing I decided I wanted another service for Business Logic.

Being that I'll have several applications interfacing with the business logic layer I assumed creating another restful service with Web API would be the best approach. With that said, I'm scratching my after learning everything regarding models and entity framework.  Being that the DAL is interfacing with the database I'm assuming I won't be using models at all in this new project and just building a controller that call my DAL service.  Is this correct or is there something I'm missing entirely here?

And if I'm not missing anything can someone point me in the right direction on how to call a restful service from a restful service?

Comment: I *believe* what you're saying sounds correct. You'll only need a Web Api for anything that the client needs to do while the page is already loaded (like if you were using Angular, for example), or if you're accessing the data from a non-web platform (like a native app). In standard ASP MVC, you don't really need Web Api, except for adding additional functionality. If you're just learning, I'd ignore Web Api for now.

Comment: hmm so in my solution was using Web API a poor choice for the Data Access Layer?  Is standard ASP MVC a more suitable approach?

Comment: Well, Web API isn't really a "data access layer" in its own right. But aside from that, I'm not sure I'd go so far as to say it's a "poor choice." It's an awesome framework for modern sites, but yeah, if you're just learning, I'd probably start with straight-MVC, then add Web API if you come across a real need for that.

Comment: Understood.. so basically this my desired architecture:

[Mobile-API  &  .NET Frontend Application] ->
[Business Logic Layer (interfaces with DAL, third-party api such as facebook linkedin etc)] -> [Data Access Layer (EF6)] -> [Database]

Based on what your saying really only the Mobile API would benefit the most from using Web API. If I were to treat each layer as a separate project in my solution would my BLL and DAL have to be restful in order to interface with each other?  Or is there a better approach I'm missing?

I'll update my original question if this is starting to go too off-topic

Comment: Yeah, I think all that sounds reasonable. Within your web server, I see no reason to make web requests to yourself, those will perform very poorly. The separation of concerns and whatnot can be enforced through code security and access protection across DLLs. A Web API will only come in handy if you need someone else to be able to interface with you, or if you want to reduce page refreshes in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Web Api can add value to an MVC application if you want to post or fetch data server-side without a postback.

As for services, it's common to put business logic in the controller and have the controller call an internal library that acts as the DAL.

Example...

**MyProject.soln**

- MyProject.Library (this is your DAL)
- MyProject.Services (Web API)
- MyProject.Web (MVC site)

I like a MVVM/Repository/Mapper pattern. It's extra work up front but very extensible and pretty [SOLID](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design). It typically includes:

1. Data models that represent objects in the database
2. Repositories for each (or most) models that do *ONLY* CRUD operations. No transformations.
3. View Models that represent the data I need in views or service controllers
4. Mapper classes that transform my data models to View Models.

**Controller example**

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(MyViewModel viewModel)  
{  
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
    {  
        return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);  
    }  
    var modelMapper = new ModelMapper();  
    var model = modelMapper.getModelFromViewModel(viewModel);  
    var modelRepository = new ModelRepository();  
    modelRepository.Save(model);  
    return Ok();  
}
```